# Split point track based on time

Tags: postgis, postgresql

With **PostgreSQL 13.6**
have a table of multiple GPS points already group by `track_id` (HEX number not sequential), and from where `ST_Makeline` is made to build a line.

Some of these tracks have a time gap between them bigger than a given value (say 10 minutes).
Need to split the `track_id` where these gaps exits, to a `track_id` (before 1st gap) and `track_id+1` (after 1st gap) ... `track_id+n` (after n_st gap).

The `track_id` is a non-sequential large intervals HEX number, so no issues on adding a few additional units (1 to 2 gaps per track) to it.

The actual location `geom` is irrelevant in the analysis, since the points in the gap can be close (time spent on the same position) or far apart (loose of reception).

This is only to clean and organize data, before any further analysis.

Table example:

| track_id | geom | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | aaaa | 10:01 |
| 123 | aaab | 10:02 |
| 123 | aaac | 10:05 |
| 123 | aaad | 10:45 |
| 123 | aaae | 10:47 |
| 123 | aaaf | 10:49 |
| 234 | aaab | 10:52 |
| 234 | aaac | 10:55 |
| 234 | aaaa | 10:58 |

to build, new column 'new_track_id`:

| track_id | geom | time | new_track_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | aaaa | 10:01 | 123 |
| 123 | aaab | 10:02 | 123 |
| 123 | aaac | 10:05 | 123 |
| 123 | aaad | 10:45 | 124 |
| 123 | aaae | 10:47 | 124 |
| 123 | aaaf | 10:49 | 124 |
| 234 | aaab | 10:52 | 234 |
| 234 | aaac | 10:55 | 234 |
| 234 | aaaa | 10:58 | 234 |

```
create table public.testtime
        (id SERIAL primary key,
        track_id varchar,
        time1 time);

--Test data:

    insert into public.testtime (track_id, time1)
        values (123,    '10:01:00'),
               (123,    '10:02:00'),
               (123,    '10:05:00'),
               (123,    '10:45:00'),
               (123,    '10:47:00'),
               (123,    '10:49:00'),
               (234,    '10:52:00'),
               (234,    '10:55:00'),
               (234,    '10:58:00');
```

**EDIT:**

to verify that `time_dif` is bigger than treshold:

```sql
UPDATE table SET
chk_dif=(CASE WHEN time_dif>'00:10' THEN TRUE END)
```

to populate the row after the true : **not working**

```sql
UPDATE table SET
chk_dif2=(CASE WHEN chk_dif=TRUE THEN TRUE
               WHEN chk_dif IS NULL THEN (SELECT LAG(chk_dif2 OVER (PARTITION BY track_id ORDER BY time))
               ELSE FALSE END)
```

It copies the TRUE from chk_dif to chk_dif2, but not repeat the chk_dif2 on the next rows, has applicable.

To change the track_id (simplify for now, change the last digit to 'x' : is not more an HEX, and only allows for a gap) looking for better

```sql
UPDATE table SET
new_track_id =
CASE WHEN chk_dif2=TRUE THEN CONCAT(LEFT(track_id,LENGTH(track_id)),'X') END)
```

**EDIT2:**

**The problem** is on the second step, to copy the TRUE for the next rows, as applicable to the second part of the segment.

Comment: What is the data type of the time field

Comment: is a 'timestamp without time zone' : not included the portion of YYYYMMDD on the tables above for clarity

Comment: I would calculate a time diff column first, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691462/postgresql-calculate-difference-between-rows. But I dont know how to increment after that

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a pure SQL question, so it might be a better fit for dba.stackexchange.com, but then again, it looked like a bit of fun for a saturday morning. :-)

This is hideous, but it looks like it works:

```
SELECT
    *,
    SUM(increment) OVER (PARTITION BY track_id ORDER BY time1 ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS idoffset
FROM (SELECT
        *,  
        CASE
          WHEN time1 - LAG(time1) OVER (PARTITION BY track_id ORDER BY time1) > '00:10' THEN 1
          ELSE 0
        END AS increment
      FROM testtime) tt1
;
```

**Output**

```
 id | track_id |  time1   | increment | idoffset
----+----------+----------+-----------+----------
  1 | 123      | 10:01:00 |         0 |        0
  2 | 123      | 10:02:00 |         0 |        0
  3 | 123      | 10:05:00 |         0 |        0
  4 | 123      | 10:45:00 |         1 |        1
  5 | 123      | 10:47:00 |         0 |        1
  6 | 123      | 10:49:00 |         0 |        1
  7 | 234      | 10:52:00 |         0 |        0
  8 | 234      | 10:55:00 |         0 |        0
  9 | 234      | 10:58:00 |         0 |        0
(9 rows)
```

First we use a window function, as suggested in a comment, to compute a column `increment` which is 1 for the first sample in every new group, and 0 everywhere else. Then, for each row, we sum the increments of all preceding rows in the group, which gives the `idoffset` to add to the id. We can’t use a window function in a window function call, so let’s go for a sub-select.